Generate a page Gutenberg from a post , cannot display the image
I created a form to generate a page so I can edit with Gutenberg. I have 2 blocks, the text and the image. The problem is that I cannot display the image, I have the "alt" and the icon :
enter image description here
The image url works, before that I added the image in the html
    ```    $post_data['post_content'] = str_replace('<!-- /wp:html -->', '', $post_data['post_content']);

        // Get the URL of the attached image
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);

        // Construct the post content with the image using Gutemberg block syntax
        $post_content = "
                <figure class='wp-block-image'>
                <img src=$image_url
                </figure>";

        // Append the image block and the closing HTML tags
        $post_data['post_content'] .= $post_content . '<!-- /wp:html -->';
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

but I don't want the image to be in the block text and I want it to be in a image block so I can edit it in gutemberg, so I tried this  :

/**
     * Form to create a button to submit and generate a page
     * @return void
     */
    public function woosterPartnerPluginSection()
    {
    ?>
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <form method="POST" action="" >
                <input type="hidden" name="submit-gutenberg" value="gutenberg">
                <button type="submit"style="margin-right: 10px;">Gutenberg</button>
            </form>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <input type="hidden" name="submit-elementor" value="elementor">
                <button type="submit">Elementor</button>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    }

    /***
     * To download image from the URL
     * @return void
     */
    public function download_image()
    {
        // Check if the button Gutenberg is clicked
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            //if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            $image_url = 'https://cdn-img.wooster.fr/app/uploads/2023/09/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1.webp?lossy=1&ssl=1&w=500';
            // wp function for sideloading images from URL and attaching them to the media library
            $image = media_sideload_image($image_url, 'Image téléchargée depuis l\'URL');
            return $image;
        }
        // Return null if the button other than Gutenberg is clicked
        return null;
    }

    /***
     * To insert the media in library and get the attachment id
     * @return string $image
     */
    public function insert_to_media($image)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            // it returns the attachment id
            $attachment = wp_insert_attachment(array(
                'post_title' => 'Image Wooster téléchargée',
                'post_content' => 'Image wooster',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
            ), $image);

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment, $image);
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment, $attach_data);


            return $attachment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /***
     * Creates the post with the Json data and image
     * @return void
     */
    public function create_post()
    {
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            // Download and insert the image into the media library
            $image = $this->download_image();
            $attachment_id = $this->insert_to_media($image);

            // Check if the image insertion was successful
            if (!$attachment_id) {
                echo "Image insertion failed. Please try again.";
                return;
            }
            // Get the URL of the attached image
            $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id);

            // Define the post content
            $post_content = '';

            // Add paragraph block
            $post_content .= '<!-- wp:paragraph -->';
            $post_content .= '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget vehicula orci, ut iaculis ex. Donec sed ornare nisi. Donec non sollicitudin ex. Aliquam at leo non odio hendrerit consectetur. Sed porttitor lacus placerat metus viverra facilisis. Aenean gravida ornare purus, ut posuere lectus dictum a. Nunc nisi leo, porta ut porta et, porttitor quis ante. In id arcu in sem vulputate fermentum. Vivamus libero augue, finibus id eros in, gravida vestibulum ex. Quisque ultrices, odio et consectetur vestibulum, arcu mi elementum nulla, a elementum massa libero quis nibh. Aenean pulvinar diam sem, a auctor nisl ullamcorper at.</p>';
            $post_content .= '<!-- /wp:paragraph -->';

            // Add image block
            $post_content .= '<!-- wp:image {"id":' . $attachment_id . '} -->';
            $post_content .= '<figure class="wp-block-image">';
            $post_content .= '<img src="' . esc_url($image_url) . '" alt="Wooster Image">';
            $post_content .= '</figure>';
            $post_content .= '<!-- /wp:image -->';

            // Create the post data
            $post_data = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_title' => 'Partenariat Wooster',
                'post_content' => $post_content,
            );

            // Insert the post
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

            // Check if the post was successfully created
            if ($post_id) {
                $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);
                // Redirect to the created post
                wp_redirect($post_url);
                exit();
            } else {
                // Handle post creation failure
                echo "Post creation failed. Please try again.";
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
new WoosterPartnerPresentation();


I closed it but the problem is still the same

I think there is an error with the wp_insert_attachment, because in the media, I don't have the image attached
